# How can a system of 2 gases be in thermical equilibirum but not in mechanical or chemical equilibrium?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas, non-equilibrium

This question is asked on my Thermodynamics course, and I don't know the answer, at least to the 1st part.

Regarding the 2nd part: I do believe that some chemical reactions may occur when 2 reactants are in thermal equilibrium.

However, I can't imagine how 2 gases in thermal equilibrium may not be also in mechanical equilibrium...

Comment: Can you describe your current understanding of what it means to be in thermal, mechanical, and chemical equilibrium?

Comment: Well:

Mechanical equilibrium: total force = 0
Chemical equilibrium = no chemical reactions occurring
Thermal equilibrium = I don't know, my textbook says that it is different from thermodynamical equilibrium, and that thermodynamical equilibrium Only occurs if termal, mechanical and chemical equilibrium occur, despite not explaining well the diferences between termal and thermodynamical

Answer (score 0):

Take a cylinder, fill it with two kinds of *ideal* gasses separated by a fixed position diathermal but other wise nonpermeable wall so that one gas has higher pressure than the other. Now let the system equilibrate thorugh heat exchange at the end of which $T_1=T_2=T_0$. If we, therefore, set from the beginning $n_1, V_1$ and $n_2, V_2$ so that $p_1 =\frac{n_1RT_0}{V_1} \ne p_2 =\frac{n_1RT_0}{V_2}$ then the system stays in thermal equilibrium without being in either mechanical or chemical equilibrium.